# Programming if else in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I use regex to program the following set of data into adding a character in equal position after the certain character in the first column, depending on the type of data in the first column?

I was using this command `^(.{5})\s*` by changing the number in the braces {} but it is to manual for large data set. I was trying if else condition but I could not figure out how to use it.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgelD.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux3Rz.png)

Thank you,

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting. Clarify your question with some sample data. I can see the images but they are not sufficient.

Comment: Why are you posting screenshots of data? This is useless. Post the data.

Comment: I am sorry  but i cant copy paste the text when i write them in the format, the spacing are not accordingly.

Comment: Paste the lines into the question and add four spaces at the start of each line. That will format them as code and so we will see the correct spacing. Another method: paste the lines in, then select them and then press the control+k keys.

Comment: -9,60  -1,39       
-9,60  0       
-9,60  1,39       
-9,20  -3,46       
-9,20  -2,08            
-8      -5,54       
-8      -4,16       
-8      -2,77       
-8      -1,39       
-8      0       
-8      1,39       
0  -9,70       
0  -8,31       
0  -6,93        
0,40  -9,01       
0,40  -7,62       
0,40  -6,24       
0,40  -4,85       
0,40  -3,46       
4  -8,31       
4  -6,93       
4  -5,54       
4  -4,16

Comment: It doesnt works